# refer a variable in another linux

Tags: bash

I have a script test.sh as follows

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "$1"
```

I am calling that script from another script like as follows

```
#!/bin/bash
declare -A val
val[first]="./test.sh ${value} | grep testing "

for KEY in "${!val[@]}"; do
  value="testing"
  echo "${val[$KEY]}"
done
```

`echo "${val[$KEY]}"` returns `./test.sh | grep testing`

It is not printing value of value variable. why?

Comment: Side note: please don't use code like this in Production shell scripts.  ;)  (It looks like you're just playing around to see how the shell works, which is fine, of course.)

Comment: but I need to interpret theoutput from the script so only

Comment: I can't make out this comment at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So far, your script defines the variable but does not evaluate it:

You assign `"./test.sh ${value} | grep testing "`, but `${value}` will be expanded at the time of *this* assignment. But, at this point, you did not define `value` yet, so it is empty, and the string becomes `"./test.sh  | grep testing"`. Use single quotes (`'`) instead of double quotes (`"`) to prevent the shell from expanding the variable:

```
'./test.sh ${value} | grep testing '
```

Later you `echo` the value of the variable. If you want to *execute* the `./test.sh ...` command which you stored in the variable, you need to evaluate it, for example

```
eval "${val[$KEY]}"
```